# Split list into two lists, odd and even, using a lambda

Tags: python, lambda, split

This is what I have:

```
ev_filt = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, list1)
od_filt = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, list1)

ev_list = list(ev_filt)
od_list = list(od_filt)

length = int(input("Enter the number of words yer gon pass"))

# initialize the list using for loop
for i in range(0, length):
   item = int(input("Pass a number bro" + str(i+1) + " :"))
   list1.append(item)
   
print(ev_list)
print(od_list)
```

I've tried to continue with this template, but it won't work.

Why?

How do I solve this?

Comment: Please be more precise with your problem. Don't just say it won't work. Do you have an error? Does it give a wrong result? It will be easier to help with some context.

Comment: The integers are not converted to the two lists: odd numbers and even numbers.'

Comment: It seems like you are building your list at the end of your logic and sorting them into even and odd before that... You have to have the list built by the user input THEN sort them into even and odd. Code runs in order from top to bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, code runs from top to bottom in order. You sort your `list1` into odd and even before it's initialized and before there are values in the list. Switch the order and you should be golden:

```
length = int(input("Enter the number of words yer gon pass"))

# initialize the list using for loop
list1=[]
for i in range(0, length):
   item = int(input("Pass a number bro" + str(i+1) + " :"))
   list1.append(item)

ev_filt = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, list1)
od_filt = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, list1)

ev_list = list(ev_filt)
od_list = list(od_filt)

   
print(ev_list)
print(od_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension:

```
listTwo = [num for num in listOne if num % 2 == 0]
listThree = [num for num in listOne if num % 2 != 0]
```

Comment: Can you add more explaination and/or link to documentation ? You can read [answer] for more precisions